# Magento: select from database

Tags: php, oop, mysql, magento

I am working on my first module for magento version 1.3.2.3.
I have created a simple table (not EAV, just a primary key and 2 columns) and some classes to access it, following [Alan Storm's articles](http://alanstorm.com/) which helped me a lot, but I can't figure out how to make a simple select: Alan explains how to load with the primary key, but not selecting rows that match some value.

In *normal MySQL* I'd write:

```
SELECT *  
FROM my_table  
WHERE some_field = '" . $someValue . "'
```

I've found a snippet which gives me the result I want:

```
$resource = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource();  
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');  
$select = $read->select()
               ->from('my_table')
               ->where('some_field = ?', $someValue);  
return $read->fetchAll($select);
```

But there have to be an easier/prettier solution, using the model class I've created. The result will be a single row, not a collection.
I've tried everything I could think of, like:

```
return Mage::getModel('modulename/classname')->select()->where('some_field = ?', $comeValue);
return Mage::getModel('modulename/classname')->load()->where('some_field = ?', $comeValue);  
return Mage::getModel('modulename/classname')->load(array('some_field = ?', $comeValue));
```

and more stuff, but no luck so far: what am I missing??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how this is achieved in the CoreUrlRewrite Model class:

```
public function loadByIdPath($path)
{
    $this->setId(null)->load($path, 'id_path');
    return $this;
}
```

You can create similar methods in your model classes. You can also use the alternative form of the load method anywhere in your code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('modulename/classname')->load($someValue, 'some_field');
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to use [your model's Collection](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections) for that.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('mygroup/mymodel')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('some_field',$some_value);

foreach($collection as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}

var_dump($collection->getFirstItem());
var_dump($collection->getLastItem());
```

Comment: hi Alan, thanks for answering. I tried your solution and it also works, but in this case, as I know the result is a single row, I think silvo's solution is better.
Interesting though the first and last method, I'll keep them in mind.

Comment: @Refilon Sounds like you want to ask a new question, not comment on an old one

Comment: Just a slight correction: It must be `getModel`, not `getMode`